# Switching from one window to active window

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

Upon logging in, a new window will open up to enter credentials, after credentials were entered, the login window will close, i was able to switch from the original window to login window but switching back to the active window does not go thru, i use the code

```
 Set<String> allHandles2 = driver.getWindowHandles();

 String currentWindowHandle2 = allHandles2.iterator().next();

 allHandles.remove(allHandles2.iterator().next());

 String lastHandle1 = allHandles2.iterator().next();

        driver.switchTo().window(lastHandle);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("Directory")).click();
```

but this one does not work on switching back to the active window, i have previously used the same logic on switching from active window to another and it works, but switching back to the active window will not let me in

need help with this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used incorrect variable name

```
String lastHandle1 = allHandles2.iterator().next();
driver.switchTo().window(**lastHandle**);
```

Instead it should be

> driver.switchTo().window(**lastHandle1**);

Hope this helps.